# how can i get my store lat and long in db to place direction in map PHP

Tags: php

how can i change my end value from the latitude and longtitude from my db 
i cant get my destination right because my end value is not getting the lat and long in my database

```
<div id="floating-panel">
<b>Start: </b>
<select id="start">
<option value="Tagaytay Summer House">vvvvvv</option>
  <option value="penn station, new york, ny">Penn Station</option>
  <option value="grand central station, new york, ny">Grand Central Station</option>
  <option value="625 8th Avenue, New York, NY, 10018">Port Authority Bus Terminal</option>
  <option value="staten island ferry terminal, new york, ny">Staten Island Ferry Terminal</option>
  <option value="101 E 125th Street, New York, NY">Harlem - 125th St Station</option>
</select>
<b>End: </b>

<select id ="end">
<?php while($row = $places->fetch_object()){ ?> 
    <option  value="<?php echo $row->place; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row->place_id; ?>" data-lat="<?php echo $row->lat; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $row->lng; ?>" data-place="<?php echo $row->place; ?>" data-description="<?php echo $row->description; ?>"><?php echo $row->place; ?></option>
<?php } ?> 
</select>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
&nbsp;
<div id="warnings-panel"></div>
<script>
```

function initMap() {
        var markerArray = [];

```
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    // Create a map and center it on Tagaytay.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: {lat: 14.1153, lng: 120.9621}
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Display the route between the initial start and end selections.
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    // Listen to change events from the start and end lists.
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(
          directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
      markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // First, remove any existing markers from the map.
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
      markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }

    // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
    // WALKING directions.
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: 'WALKING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
      // markers for each step.
      if (status === 'OK') {
        document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML =
            '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        showSteps(response, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function showSteps(directionResult, markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
    // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
    // when calculating new routes.
    var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
      var marker = markerArray[i] = markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker;
      marker.setMap(map);
      marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
      attachInstructionText(
          stepDisplay, marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions, map);
    }
  }

  function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
      // of the step.
      stepDisplay.setContent(text);
      stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```